# How can we copy the artifacts from Linux to Windows server?

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins

I'm building my project on the Linux server and then manually coping the artifacts from that server to the Windows server. Actually I'm automating this process with the help of the jenkins but  don't know whether we can copy the artifacts from Linux server to the Windows server automatically or not. can we use the batch commands to do that automatically ?

Comment: You may use Samba to share.

Answer (score 0):

Can make use of the [pscp.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) it is a PuTTY scp companion.

Then Go to your windors box and open a command prompt 
(start -> run -> "cmd" press Enter)

cd to where pscp.exe is installed.
and USe the below command:

pscp -l  c:\location\of\file linuxServername:/home/user

Answer (score 0):

An other solution is to connect your Windows machine as a node of the Jenkins master.

Then, you can create a job running on the Windows machine to get the artifacts from a Linux job and copy them on the Windows machine.

You can use the [Copy Artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to do that.

It should work :)